# Perform deep copy over QImage

Tags: c++, qt

How to perform a deep copy on a QImage?

What I have is like this:

```
texture_img = camWorker->getImage();

QImage CamWorker::getImage(){
    QMutexLocker locker(&mutex);
    return QImg;
}
```

and the QImg is from a stream Video.
However I found that the `texture_img = camWorker->getImage();` only performs a shallow copy over QImage, and when the QImg is changed in another thread it creates seg-fault.
Will a deepcopy solve the problem?

Comment: I think when `QImage` has changed, Qt changes its copy and not the shared data. As docs say: `...and the data is copied only if and when a function writes to it, i.e., copy-on-write.`

Comment: `QImage` has `copy` method.

Comment: those comments would make good answers. So go ahead guys

Comment: How do you change the `QImg` in another thread? What methods do you call? You should check [threads and implicitly shared classes](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/threads-modules.html#threads-and-implicitly-shared-classes).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As Amartel has pointed out, `QImage` provides a `copy` method.

```
QImage image_copy = image.copy();
```

See [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#copy) for more details.